# Computer rapid beeps

Tags: boot, post

My workstation (MSI Motherboard H67MA-E45 B3) has been stuck three separate times in the boot sequence, during which it makes constant rapid beeps.

I have checked the RAM with memtest in the past and it seems fine. Also, on two of the occasions that the computer was stuck in the boot, I removed all DIMMs and put back one at a time but it did not boot.

I finally realized that whenever I remove the hard drive connectors (SATA and power), and plug it back in, the computer will then boot. SMART is not showing anything wrong with the hard drives, yet. I have no idea what this could mean or if there is any test that I can perform.

Comment: Have you checked for a stuck keyboard key? Not sure if this can cause an issue as early as POST, but that fits the symptoms a second or two later.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I checked booting up without keyboard and mouse and I still got the same problem.

Comment: Please [edit] and add the make and model of your PC and the manufacturer of your BIOS.